# With hasNextInput() in a while loop it gives the loop for every String given but I want it to prompt once

Tags: string, input, while-loop, java.util.scanner

```
    public void choice(){

    this.damageCalculator();
    story.typeWriterEffect("Give your choice of attack: \n");

            while (!input.hasNextInt()){
                story.typeWriterEffect("Please enter the correct number (1, 2 or 3).(ERROR NO INT)\n");
                story.typeWriterEffect("Give your choice of attack: \n");
                input.reset();
                input.next();
            }
            setUserChoiceOfAttack(input.nextInt());

        if(getUserChoiceOfAttack() > 0 && getUserChoiceOfAttack() < 4){
            this.userAttackMoment();
        } else {
            story.typeWriterEffect("Please enter the correct number (1, 2 of 3).(ERROR INPUT INVALID)\n");
            this.choice();
            }
}
```

Problem:
If you enter "Lol nope" at the input then it will output "Please enter the ..." and "Give your choice..." twice (for every word typed and seperated with a space.
It all runs fine but the one thing bugging me is that I only want it to repeat once if the user enters something he shouldn't (even if it's multiple strings seperated by spaces).

Beginning programmer here and any feedback on my code writing is appreciated!

EDIT:

The comment of pivu0 worked out!
This is my fixed code and works perfectly!

```
public void choice(){

    this.damageCalculator();

        story.typeWriterEffect("Give your choice of attack: \n");

        boolean loopCondition = true;
        while(loopCondition == true){

            try{                    
                player.setPlayerChoiceOfAttack(Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine()));

                if(player.getPlayerChoiceOfAttack() > 0 && player.getPlayerChoiceOfAttack() < 4){
                    loopCondition = false;
                } else {
                    story.typeWriterEffect("Please enter the correct number (1, 2 of 3).(ERROR INPUT INVALID)\n");
                    }
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e){
                loopCondition = true;
                story.typeWriterEffect("Please enter the correct number (1, 2 or 3).(ERROR NO INT)\n");
                story.typeWriterEffect("Give your choice of attack: \n");
            }
        }
        this.userAttackMoment();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that input is an instance of `Scanner` by the methods you are using.

If you read the documentation of `hasNextInt` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()

You see that it checks wether the next TOKEN is an int. For the scanner class, tokens are seperated by spaces. So it will check your first word, conclude that 'lol' is not an Int, go through the loop, conclude that 'nop' is not an Int, go trough loop again...

Try getting the whole scanner input as a string `input.nextLine()` and try checking if this string is an Integer or not by using `Integer.parseInt`

If the input.nextLine() is an integer, it will go out of the loop. If it's not, a new input is checked:

```
int number=0;
boolean loopCondition = false;
while(!loopCondition){
 try {
    number = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine())
    loopCondition = true;
    } 
 catch (NumberFormatException e){
    story.typeWriterEffect("Please enter the correct number (1, 2 or 3).(ERROR NO INT)\n");
            story.typeWriterEffect("Give your choice of attack: \n");
    loopCondition = false;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have a boolean variable to check the attempt

```
//attempt is initally false
public void choice(boolean attempt){

    this.damageCalculator();

        story.typeWriterEffect("Give your choice of attack: \n");

            while (!input.hasNextInt()){
                story.typeWriterEffect("Please enter the correct number (1, 2 or 3).(ERROR NO INT)\n");
                story.typeWriterEffect("Give your choice of attack: \n");
                input.reset();
                input.next();
            }
                setUserChoiceOfAttack(input.nextInt());

        if(getUserChoiceOfAttack() > 0 && getUserChoiceOfAttack() < 4){
            this.userAttackMoment();
        } else if(!attempt){
            story.typeWriterEffect("Please enter the correct number (1, 2 of 3).(ERROR INPUT INVALID)\n");
            this.choice(true);
            }
}
```